# Why is material colour's assignment not working properly?

Tags: materials

I am following the making cup tutorial and I have already finished making the cup, and I am kind of curious what if I assign a different colour for my cup's inside instead of my cup's outside colour.

But, as I assign the colour to it, the colour has a strange pattern of the cup's outside colour like this:

[image]

I check the wireframe of my mesh, but I don't see any of the cup's inside mesh intersect with the outside one. What is the problem? What's wrong with this? Why is the assigned material's colour not
working properly?

Here is the blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/a237b6c6ef234f83ae86cd96951309d7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

You have overlapping faces, some are orange, so select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* to remove these faces:

[image]

You still have orange faces, it's because on the bottom you have a ring of faces with the orange material. As you have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier it tends to stretch the faces. Switch to transparency and select this faces ring:

[image]

Assign it the blue material and you are good:

[image]

Comment: how do you edit the object while having colour? Are you edit it in rendered view mode?

Comment: In order to switch to Edit mode, select the object and press Tab, or Ctrl Tab to switch from a interaction mode to another. You can edit an object in whatever display mode you want: Solid, Material, Rendered preview modes...

Comment: Thanks moonboots